# Visa requirements for a Norwegian Permanent Resident to remotely work for a UK employer

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, norway

I am a non-EU citizen and a Norwegian Permanent Resident. I am exploring an opportunity to remotely (from Norway) work for a UK company and I am confused about the type of visa, if any, that I need to apply in UK. Do I need to apply for any Visa, such as Tier-2, to work for the UK employer while I am resident in Norway?

Thanks for your comments!

Comment: You only need a UK visa if you are going to travel to the UK. Will you be traveling to the UK? If so, for how long? What will you be doing while you are there?

Comment: What is your nationality? Asking because of short visit situations.

Answer (score 1):

You only need UK visa if you are going to be resident in the UK for any period of time. Note that this may include short business visits depending on your nationality.